# Quick sort in Visual Basic

Tags: visual-studio, quicksort

I tried to make a quick-sort in VB2015, however when I run it, the values don't sort fully (however it does almost sort). I'm fairly sure that the problem has something to do with the two recurring lines.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles   Button1.Click
    numbers = TextBox1.Text.Split()
    Dim tempstring As String
    Form2.Show()
    tempstring = ""
    quicksort(numbers, numbers.Length() - 1, 0)
    For Each a As String In numbers
        tempstring = tempstring + a + " "
    Next
    TextBox2.Text = tempstring
    Form2.Show()
    Form2.Chart1.Series(0).Points.DataBindY(numbers)
End Sub

Public Sub quicksort(list As Array, high As Integer, low As Integer)
    MessageBox.Show(Str(high) + " " + Str(low))
    ListView1.Items.Add(Str(high) + " " + Str(low))
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim pivot As Integer
    'pivot = (high + low) / 2
    pivot = high
    If high > low + 1 And low >= 0 Then
        i = low
        For c = low + 1 To high
            If Int(list(c)) <= Int(list(pivot)) Then
                swap(list, c, i)
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next
        quicksort(numbers, i - 2, low)
        quicksort(numbers, high, i)
    End If
End Sub
Public Sub swap(list As Array, x As Integer, y As Integer)
    Dim temp As Integer
    temp = list(x)
    list(x) = list(y)
    list(y) = temp
    Form2.Chart1.Series(0).Points.DataBindY(numbers)
    'pause()
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you really want to do the sort manually or just use Linq to sort the list with one line of code?

Comment: I realise that i can sort in one line. However my teacher (year 12) set this task and no one was able to come close. So rather than trying to teach us she just sent everybody a link to one online. I thought i was close and i wanna be able to finish! (am i close)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but somebody may come across this. Your SWAP sub needs to pass the parameters ByRef, or the swap is only taking place inside the sub's variables and not within your QuickSort routine.